# Синтаксический разбор простого(?)предложения

Tags: синтаксис

В Одноклассниках в группе "Русский язык" задали вопрос.

Надо найти ошибку в синтаксическом разборе простого предложения:

**Казалось, никакое сердце не может не растаять, не ответить.***

> *Варианты: а) распространенное в) двусоставное, полное с) осложнено вводным словом d) повествовательное, невосклицательное.*

Посоветовался с филологом, пришли к в выводу, что предложение не простое, а сложное. На что указывает безличный глагол "казалось" и возможность вставить союз "что".

А как вы думаете? Чем является здесь "казалось" вводным или безличным глаголом? Ведь если  **"казалось"** вводное, тогда в задании ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Надо найти ошибку в синтаксическом разборе...
>
> Посоветовался с филологом, пришли к в выводу, что предложение не
>   простое, а сложное. На что указывает безличный глагол "казалось" и
>   возможность вставить союз "что".

Серж, по-моему, Вы не там ищете ошибку.

Да, в начале предложения вводное слово ***казалось*** *"по значению приближается к простому предложению в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения с зависимыми отношениями"* (из Розенталя).  Но считать это слово в разбираемом предложении вводным  — не ошибка.

Ошибка же в приведённом разборе, по-моему, в том, что не отмечена осложнённость предложения однородными частями сказуемого:

*(не может) **не растаять, не ответить.***

Comment: Да, наверное, вы правы: помимо вводного слова, надо было указать и однородность сказуемых.

Comment: Ну это-то точно не ошибка. Разве синтаксический разбор обязательно требует упоминания всех однородных членов? Кстати я очень сомневаюсь, что утверждение "здесь однородное сказуемое" само по себе верное. Тут однородна только основная часть составного глагольного сказуемого...

Comment: _behemothus: Кстати я очень сомневаюсь, что утверждение "здесь однородное сказуемое" само по себе верное. Тут однородна только основная часть составного глагольного сказуемого..._ === С этим согласен. Сейчас попробую исправить свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Формулировка вообще оставляет только гадать, что хотел сказать автор.
Во-первых, это не "варианты" разбора, а его составляющие, пункты. Разбор есть совокупность всех четырех утверждений. 
Во-вторых, по грамматике "казалось" может быть и вводным, а может быть и частью бессоюзного сложного, **в задании от того ошибки** не прибавится, оно само по себе бестолковое. Другое дело, что трактовка предложения как сложносочиненного здесь выглядит совершенно искусственно, зачем искать сложности там, где все прекрасно имеет простое объяснение? Принцип бритвы Оккама и в грамматике работает.

Так что на один вопрос я могу дать ответ. По классическим представлениям, "Казалось" здесь вводное, иное очень уж вычурно.

Ошибок же я не вижу. Да, осложненность однородными частями имеет место, но отсутствие упоминания этого в обычном грамматическом разборе считать ошибкой нельзя.

Скорее всего ошибка не в разборе как таковом, а в отступлении от методики, апологетом которой является учитель, эту задачку придумавший, или, того хуже, тетя из РОНО.

Comment: Да, насчет пунктов автору указали, что это ошибка. Указали еще, что в пунктах не указан тип предложения ( не знаю, можно ли считать это ошибкой, в самом задании ведь сказано, что предложение простое). Насчет "казалось" разобрались - это вводное.  Я тоже не уверен, надо ли указывать все однородные части, осложняющие предложение.

Comment: _Серж: Я тоже не уверен, надо ли указывать все однородные части, осложняющие предложение._ === Гм… Вы считаете, что можно было бы при разборе просто написать, что предложение осложнённое без указания на то, **чем именно** оно осложнено? И если бы в рассматриваемом предложении отсутствовало бы вводное _(Никакое сердце не может не растаять, не ответить)_, Вы бы написали, что оно **неосложнённое?**

Comment: Нет, конечно. Преподаватель говорит ( в Однокласниках) , если, например, ученик при разборе всё правильно подчеркнул, значит, он их увидел. Все зависит от того, требует ли преподаватель словесно указывать все осложняющие конструкции.

Comment: Слава, это вопрос из теста. Т.е. разбор делал не ученик, а был готовый разбор. Надо было лишь найти ошибку. Во-вторых, как отметил behemothus, "это не "варианты" разбора, а его составляющие, пункты". В задании именно варианты. Как видно, и само задание уже неграмотно составлено.

Comment: *Вы считаете, что можно было бы при разборе просто написать, что предложение осложнённое без указания на то, чем именно оно осложнено?* - нет, я просто не вижу ошибки в отсутствии упоминания об осложнености. Если так разбираться, едва ли каждое предложение чем-нибудь да осложнено. Но разве есть методички, предписывающие обо всем этом говорить при грамматическом разборе?! А если и есть, то и получается, что "ошибка" только в отступлении от методички.

Comment: _behemothus: я просто не вижу ошибки в отсутствии упоминания об осложнености…Разве есть методички, предписывающие обо всем этом говорить при грамматическом разборе?!_ === См. у Литневской: _**Простое предложение разбирается по следующей схеме:** 
<...>
7. По наличию осложняющих членов:
1) неосложненное,
2) **осложненное:**
— однородными членами предложения;
— обособленными членами предложения;
— вводными словами, вводными и вставными конструкциями,
— прямой речью;
— обращением._ 
http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#35

Comment: Ну тогда это ошибка только с точки зрения методички, о чем я уже и говорил. По сути - ошибка есть что-то неправильное в сказанном. А умолчание разве можно признать ошибкой?